# Using reCAPTCHA with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

Does the reCAPTCHA usercontrol post a request to http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify to verify the entered text matches the captcha, or is this done in the dll?

Comment: What I'm asking is when you call Page.IsValid or repatcha.IsValid, does that make an API call to Google?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it does make requests to Google.

The first is a request from the client for a captcha image

The second is a request from the server to validate the entered text against the image

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html